# Как убрать повторяющейся код "if else" в контролерах?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Код в класах модели

```
public class IncomingLetter : TypeOfLetter
 {}
public class SendLetter : TypeOfLetter
 {}
public class SpamLetter : TypeOfLetter
 {}

public class DataBaseContext : DbContext
{
   public DataBaseContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
   {}

   public DbSet<IncomingLetter> IncomingLetters { get; set; }
   public DbSet<SendLetter> SendLetters { get; set; }
   public DbSet<SpamLetter> SpamLetters { get; set; }
}
```

Код в контроллерах

```
public class MessageController : Controller
{
     public  ActionResult SomeControl(int numberOfType)
     {
         using (var db = new DataBaseContext())
         {
              if(numberOfType==1)
              {
                   db.IncomingLetters.Where(x=>...)
              }
              else if(numberOfType==2)
              {
                   db.SendLetters.Where(x=>...)
              }
              else if(numberOfType==3)
              {
                   db.SpamLetters.Where(x=>...)
              }
         }
    }
}
```

Я маю багато контроллерив с повторяющемися действиями в болах "if else"
И я не могу написать метод который вынесет эти блоки из контроллеров потому что нужно возвращать разные типы данних. Только разве что использовать тип "dynamic" но тогда не рабонает intelli sense

Comment: uses switch case.

Comment: switch case not will not reduce the number of code repeats in controllers

Comment: ActionResult тут непричём. на него можно не смотреть. Проблема в том что List<DbSet<ITypesOfLetter>> не принимает тип <DbSet<IncomingLetters>> В этом и проблема. я не понимаю какраз почему так происходит.

Comment: @SashaDvorkovyi если это возможно, покажите как именно он не принимает, из кода в вопросе не вижу этой проблемы

Comment: Добавил картинки. Если использовать интерфейс а не клас проблема такая же. Это я клас просто попробывать решил.

Comment: Откуда взялся `List<DbSet<ITypesOfLetter>>`? В показанном коде нет никакого списка. И что именно используется: `ITypesOfLetter` или `TypeOfLetter`? Неужели так сложно нормально скопировать код? Приведите _реальный_ код.

Comment: Так уже лучше. Но всё же код нужно публиковать текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: текст кода показан. List<DbSet<TypesOfLetter>> я пробывал как решение даной проблемы но оно не работает. Вот я его и удалил. в тексте кода. Интерфейс ITypesOfLetter и клас TypesOfLetter и производніе класы IncomingLetters, SendLetters, SpamLetters имеют все одни и теже поля.

Comment: `List<IQueryable<ITypesOfLetter>>`

Comment: Спасибо большое. List<IQueryable<ITypesOfLetter>> этот лист работает. и сейчас я могу зделать нормальные контроллеры без повторений "if else"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ подсказал Alexandr Petrov в коментарях. выходит что то такое:

```
public class DataBaseContext : DbContext
{
    public List<IQueryable<ITypesOfLetter>> list;
    public DataBaseContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        list = new List<IQueryable<ITypesOfLetter>>();
        list.Add(IncomingLetters);
        list.Add(SendLetters);
        list.Add(SpamLetters);
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Letter> Letters { get; set; }
    public DbSet<IncomingLetter> IncomingLetters { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SendLetter> SendLetters { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SpamLetter> SpamLetters { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SpamMeil> SpamMeils { get; set; }
}
```

Код в контролерах

```
public class MessageController : Controller
{
     public  ActionResult SomeControl(int numberOfType)
     {
         using (var db = new DataBaseContext())
         {
              db.list[numberOfType].Where(x=>...);
         }
    }
}
```

и больше блокы "if else" не нужны.

Answer (score 2):

Есть два варианта:

1. Как Вы правильно заметили, можно использовать dynamic types. То, что не работает IntelliSense, не должно быть проблемой - это просто небольшое визуальное неудобство.
2. Судя по вашему коду, Ваши типы реализуют интерфейс `ITypesOfLetter`. Используйте его как базовый тип для Вашей логики.

**UPD:**

После обновления вопроса с примерами - а почему бы не сделать конвертер?

Вам эти объекты нужны для работы с ними на стороне business layer'а, верно? Если да, то сделайте базовый класс (LetterPresenter) и в нем N конструкторов:

```
public LetterPresenter("ваш_тип_из_БД" obj)
{
    //копирование полей
}
```

И после этого работайте с коллекцией объектов этого класса. Да, мы только что придумали Model :)

Comment: суть в том что при обращении к базе данных она хочет конкретный тип (DbSet<IncomingLetter>) или какой то другой из заданых. ей не подойдёт тип  DbSet<TypeOfLetter>. Да и нельзя создать пару таблиц в Entity Framework с однаковым типом данных. так что может подойти решение только с dynamic((( хоть и не хотелось бы это юзать.

Comment: тогда, возможно, Вам стоит поменять БД? Сделать одну таблицу Letter, объединив в ней все поля из Ваших нескольких таблиц, сделав их nullable?

Comment: Это канешно решени. Но дело в том что я  как раз и розединил эти таблицы что бы уменьшить количество данных в них)))

Comment: Просто пробывал поразному. И решиния кроме как с методом что возвращает тип dynamic не нашол. Вот решил и других спросить. Бо dynamic это по сути свого рода костыль будет, а не хотелось бы.

Comment: а зачем уменьшать количество данных? из-за производительности?

Comment: Ну я конечно начинающий програмист и многого не знаю. Но так как я пишу почту (ноть и в учёбных целях) и если считать что писемь могут быть милионы то розбить их на разные подтипы и уменьшить их количество в одной таблице, думаю неплохая идея.